# log4j produces no output on specific Weblogic servers

Tags: log4j, weblogic, apache-commons-logging

We are distributing an application that is deployed as a bunch of WAR files in various WebLogic servers (9, 10 and 11) at various customers' sites. Those apps are using commons-logging and log4j. It works perfectly everywhere except at a specific site where no logs are generated from our app. That site is on 11g and has a bunch of other Oracle software installed (BPEL, OSB etc)

In our code, we use:

```
public class Foo {

private final static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Foo.class);

    public void bar () {
        log.trace("bar called");
        ...
```

Since we want to let the customers adapt their logs configuration, we have a configuration folder in the server CLASSPATH:

```
CLASSPATH=/opt/app/domain_foo/foo_config/:....
```

In that folder, two files for logs, commons-logging.properties:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
```

And log4j.properties: (this is a simplified one that has the same issue, actual file contains 5 loggers with various parameters)

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, fileApp

# File appender
log4j.appender.fileApp=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileApp.file=fooapp.log
log4j.appender.fileApp.maxFileSize=10240KB
log4j.appender.fileApp.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.fileApp.append=true
log4j.appender.fileApp.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileApp.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-70.70C %m%n

log4j.logger.be.foo=DEBUG
```

The file fooapp.log is created (so it was able to find the properties file) but empty.
I tried to check the log settings in Weblogic but they seem to be the same on working and not working servers.
I copied the CLASSPATH to my server and it is still working fine.

I don't really know where to look anymore. Any ideas ?

Comment: Are there any error messages in your nohup.out like this: "ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named"?

Comment: Check the server logs...

Comment: Server logs don't contain anything special. If I make a mistake in the log4j.properties on purpose, I can see that error in the server logs.

Comment: I've changed a part of the code to use log4j directly and I'm getting those logs. So the issue is definitely related to commons-logging. I've tried to set -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger in the server start parameters but it has no effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tricky but the answer is in the environment named: APPLICATIONS_DIRECTORY that should point to the path where APPLICATIONS_DIRECTORY/fooapp.log should be.  You can get the directory location from System.getenv("APPLICATIONS_DIRECTORY");